# How to remove #DIV/0 errors in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to remove or replace the DIV error with blank and i have tried to use the ISERROR function but still does not work.  This is what it looks like my data:

```
       COLA  COLB   COLC
ROW1    $0    $0   #DIV/0
ROW2               #VALUE!
```

so i get these kind of errors when i have something like above and i would like to replace with blanks.  Here is my formula that does not work.  thanks

```
=IF((ISERROR(D13-C13)/C13),"",(D13-C13)/C13)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The suggestions are all valid. The reason why your original formula does not work is the wrong placement of the round brackets. Try

```
=IF(ISERROR((D13-C13)/C13),"",(D13-C13)/C13)
```

Comment: + 1 for addressing the actual problem. Also handling error using `IsError` is the best way rather than validating each cell in a formula

Comment: Is there a way to only catch DIV/0 errors? This is what I came here to find. I can't find a IFDIV0 function, or a way to pass an "error type" as an argument to IFERROR or ISERROR to trigger a particular exception.

Comment: @MPa The `#DIV!` error only shows when the value is divided by zero. So, instead of checking for the `#DIV!` error, you could check if the divisor is 0 and act accordingly.

Comment: @teylyn True! Still, I wish I could catch specific errors, but your approach is straightforward for this particular case, thanks.

Comment: More robust: `IFERROR`, see answer below.

Answer (score 10):

**A better formula** that appears to suit your question is

```
=IFERROR((D13-C13)/C13,"")
```

Incidentally, it is **less prone to errors** as using mismatched formulas for the condition tested and the result on no-error (the present case can be regarded of this type).

If you want to stick to `ISERROR`, then [the solution by teylyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20485022/2707864) rules, of course.

Comment: Very DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).  I like it!  Other answers require you to enter in the Cell multiple times.  This solution does not.  If you're ever mixing numbers and strings then the IfError() will handle those, whereas you'd have to check that ALL values are numbers using the other answers.  A+

Answer (score 6):

Why remove the error, and instead just *don't* divide by zero?

```
=IF(C13=0,"",(D13-C13)/C13)
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
=IF(C13=0,0,(D13-C13)/C13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to leave the errors in the sheet and hide them.  This is sometimes useful, for instance `#NA` errors in a column of data when plotted on a chart show as missing rather than zero.

To hide them use conditional formatting, in the formula box

```
=ISERROR(C13)
```

and in the format box make the font colour white.

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole spreadsheet, then under menu **Home** - **Conditional Formatting** - **New Rule...** - Select **Format only cells that contain** - Under **Format only cells with** select **Errors** - Click **Format...** button - Go to the **Font** tab - Under **Color** select the same font color as the background  (such as white).

[image: New Rule Dialog]